# translationZ not working in my ConstraintLayout with map fragment

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, supportmapfragment

I have a ImageView on a Map frangment which both of them placed in a ConstraintLayout. I set android:translationZ="2dp" and then android:elevation="2dp" for ImageView but still can't see image.

map_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/testImage"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/mapView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/test"
        android:translationZ="2dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The weird thing is, I set an OnClickListener to image and I can click it. It looks like ImageView is there, on the top of map fragment but I can't see it.

How can I send map fragment to back or bring views to front?

Comment: change the fragment layout_height to fixed size for  example :80 dp
its cover entire screen so you can't see imageView

Comment: Did you try setting `android:elevation="2dp"` instead of `android:translationZ`?

Comment: @mohosyny; imageView must be on mapview. And mapview must be cover all screen.

Comment: @ReazMurshed; yes I tried elevation. Not working :(

Comment: Maybe the drawable that you are trying to set in the `ImageView` is getting some error and hence you cannot see anything even if the `ImageView` in on the top of the `fragment`?

Comment: set background instead of src and see any change happen?

Comment: @ReazMurshed; I tried add another imageview with same drawable, and you are right. I can't see  :(

Comment: @mohosyny; I tried backgroud and then android:src, now it's working :) There is a problem with app:srcCompat. But this attribute is out-of-box in Android Studio :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `app:srcCompat` with `android:src` worked fine. Final xml looks like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/testImage"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/mapView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/test"
        android:translationZ="2dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thanks to @mohosyny and @ReazMurshed.